# WPF Combobox не отображаеает элементы списка

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

`<ComboBox x:Name="Coef1" FontFamily="Dynamics" FontSize="9" Foreground="#1B3540" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  SelectedValue="{Binding TransRatioPrimary}" SelectedValuePath="Amper"  DisplayMemberPath="Caption"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=I_1_items}"/>`

С# :

```
 public class AmpersItem
    {
        public string Caption{ get; set; }
        public int Amper { get; set; }
    }
...
 public ObservableCollection<AmpersItem> I_1_items { get; set; }// = new ObservableCollection<item>();

        private void Fill_I1() 
        { 
            List<int> ampers = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75, 80, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 750, 800, 1000,
                1200, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 25000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 35000, 40000});
            I_1_items = new ObservableCollection<AmpersItem>();
            for (int i=0; i<ampers.Count; i++) 
            {
                I_1_items.Add(new AmpersItem() { Amper = ampers[i], Caption = ampers[i].ToString() + " А" });
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("I_1_items");
        }
...
 private void TransCurMainWnd_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            Fill_I1();
        }
```

Не отображаются элементы в списке. Хотя выбираются.

Comment: `Не отображаются элементы в списке. Хотя выбираются.` это как?

Comment: Когда открываешь список там пустые пункты элементов - https://ibb.co/k8wJSGX